# multithredin using dmtcp in python

Tags: python, distributed-computing, checkpoint

I like to control the checkpointing process from inside the python code. DMTCP is a a framework for checkpointing in distributed systems. It allows checkpointing python [rograms. But I wish to checkpoint a python program using a python program. Is there any python API for dmtcp or any other checkpointing library.

Answer (score 1):

DMTCP provides a simple python module that you can import in your python program.  This module allows you to access DMTCP functionality from within the python program. For example, you can do the following:

```
$ dmtcp_launch python

import dmtcp    
...
dmtcp.checkpoint()
...
dmtcp.restart()
```

For more information, checkout the python module and example programs here:
https://github.com/dmtcp/dmtcp/tree/master/contrib/python